# How to handle Unix pipe

Tags: c++, unix, pipe

How do I get the filename from redirection from the shell in my C++ code? i.e. ./MyProgram < myfile , I want to get myfile as the filename and its content line by line.

**Edit: I managed to get the input from file. Thanks for the help. However, after the looping through the file content, I want to keep user input with cin. It's like this:

```
while (true)
{
    if (cin.eof() == false)
    {
        getline(cin, line);
        cout << line;
    }else{
        cin >> choice;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the standard input is redirected from the file, there is no more input to read after you get EOF on standard input; that's what EOF means.  If you want to read from the terminal, then you probably don't want to support the I/O redirection.

Comment: Also, your question has essentially nothing to do with pipes as it stands - please retitle it appropriately.

Comment: You really should revert your edit, clarifying a question is good, changing the question to something entirely different is bad.  I'd say to ask your new question as a separate question, but it's already been answered many times.  Use `while (cin.getline(line))`.

Comment: New question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251433/checking-for-eof-in-stringgetline

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't (at least not portably).  This information is not provided to the program.  Instead, you can access the data from `myfile` (in your example) by reading from standard input.  E.g., you can use C++'s [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) with `cin` as the first parameter.

Comment: But I have to read from a file for input from the command above, not by manually entered by typing. Is there a way to get the whole line?

Comment: You can get the data from `myfile` by reading standard input.  That is the point of the redirection operator.  It lets a program read user input the same way it reads a redirected file.

Comment: Ok I did it. However, I want to keep user input after reading file with cin, and it didn't work. It keeps looping forever. I will modify my first post.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the shell, you may have inherited a descriptor representing an actual file or a pipe.  If it's an actual pipe (i.e. fifo), the name won't mean much.  But you can get the name on linux (and on Windows, but it doesn't sound like you're interested in that).

See [Getting Filename from file descriptor in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188757/getting-filename-from-file-descriptor-in-c)