# What is a better way to read a file until it ends than using istream eof?

Tags: c++, string, istream

I have read that using istream eof is "buggy" and not a "formal" way of writing code, so what is a better code to use? For example, I have the following code:

```
using namespace std; //I've heard this is bad practice also

int main(){
    string line;
    ifstream myfile("example.txt");
    while(!myfile.eof()){
        getline(myfile, line);
    }//while
    //do something with line
}//main
```

What should I replace !myfile.eof() with? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [checking for eof in string::getline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251433/checking-for-eof-in-stringgetline)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Answer (score 3):

```
if (ifstream myfile("example.txt"))
{
    while (getline(myfile, line))
    {
        ...
    }
    if (!eof(myfile))
        std::cerr << "error before end of input file\n";
}
else
    std::cerr << "error opening input file\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

The key is to realize that [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) returns a reference to the stream, and that a boolean operation on the stream reference returns `true` if the stream is OK and `false` if the previous operation failed. That includes a failure to open the file.

```
while (getline(myfile, line))
{
    // do something with line
}
```

I don't know why your original example had "do something" outside of the `while` loop.